# Metapost: How to place multliple instances of a macro

Tags: metapost

I wrote a little Metapost macro that draws a smiley. I'd like to place another instance next to the first, maybe a little larger (size is a parameter). How can I place multiple separate instances?

Here's what I have so far:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.png";
outputformat := "png";

def face(expr x) =
  begingroup
    u := 8bp;
    p := 3u;
    d := x*u;
    r := 0.3*d;
    pickup pencircle scaled p;
    fill fullcircle scaled d withcolor black;
    draw fullcircle scaled d withcolor white;
    drawdot (0,r) rotated -35 withcolor white;
    drawdot (0,r) rotated 35 withcolor white;
    draw (0,r) rotated 110 .. (0,r) rotated 180 ..
      (0,r) rotated -110 withcolor white;
  endgroup
enddef;

beginfig(1)
  face(50)
endfig;
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the other `face` into a temporary picture using `image( ... )` and then shift and scale the whole thing.

You might also want to scale everything down a little bit altogether because your units are getting close to arithmetic overflow.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.png";
outputformat := "png";

def face(expr x) =
  begingroup
    u := 8bp;
    p := 3u;
    d := x*u;
    r := 0.3*d;
    pickup pencircle scaled p;
    fill fullcircle scaled d withcolor black;
    draw fullcircle scaled d withcolor white;
    drawdot (0,r) rotated -35 withcolor white;
    drawdot (0,r) rotated 35 withcolor white;
    draw (0,r) rotated 110 .. (0,r) rotated 180 ..
      (0,r) rotated -110 withcolor white;
  endgroup
enddef;

beginfig(1)
  face(50);
  draw image( face(50); ) scaled (1.2) shifted (500bp,0) ;
endfig;
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the image() command is what I needed. But what is the value of maxdimen? I don't see it in mpman.pdf nor in the first couple pages of a google search.

Comment: @dedded Ugh, I don't actually know what it is called in MetaPost, but if you units are too large you get an error `Arithmetic overflow`.  I'll check what the number is.

Comment: @dedded It's `4096bp`, see Section 6.1 in the MetaPost manual.

Comment: You could also put the `image` into the macro, so that the macro just produced a `picture` which you could then draw or transform as you needed...

Comment: @HenriMenke, Wow, 4096 is quite the limit in a age when 7680 × 4320 is a defined monitor standard (8K UHD).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version with the `image` operator in the macro...

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.png";
outputformat := "png";

vardef face(expr diameter) = image(
    save p; pair p; p = up scaled 0.3 diameter;
    fill fullcircle scaled diameter withcolor black;
    draw fullcircle scaled diameter withcolor white;
    drawdot p rotated -35 withcolor white;
    drawdot p rotated 35 withcolor white;
    draw p rotated  110 
      .. p rotated  180 
      .. p rotated -110 withcolor white;
    ) 
enddef;

beginfig(1)
    pickup pencircle scaled 20;
    draw face(400) rotated 20 shifted 200 left;
    pickup pencircle scaled 10;
    draw face(200) scaled 1.618 shifted 200 right;
endfig;
end
```

### Notes

- `vardef` is like `def` but automatically adds the `begingroup` and `endgroup` for you.
- if you want the value of `p` restored at the `endgroup` you need to `save p;` at the beginning of the group.
- it's good practice to explicitly define your local variables, rather than re-asssign them with `:=`
- it's easier to define a pair here than to keep writing `(0, r)`.  Personally I find it easier to use `up` rather than remembering that `(0, 1)` means up...
- you can apply any translation to the `picture` and you can pass it to `draw` or `label` to put it on the page
- but don't try `draw face(200) withcolor red;` -- or rather *do* try it, and see that it's probably not a good idea.
- You might also consider doing

  ```
  picture Smiler;
  Smiler = face(360);
  draw Smiler shifted 40 right;
  draw Smiler shifted 100 right rotated 90;
  % etc
  ```