# Can I create function in MetaPost?

Tags: metapost

There are function in programming languages, for example

```
function f(int x){ return x*x; }
```

Can I use something similar in MetaPost?

Comment: There is `def` and `vardef`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536255/define-a-cube-root-function-in-metapost/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517222/metapost-how-to-place-multliple-instances-of-a-macro/517241 for example.

Comment: For an off-site tutorial you can read https://learnmetapost.onrender.com/learn-metapost/functions-and-text/ for example.

Comment: @Marijn Yes, i need it. Could you make answer?

Comment: Does any of the two questions I linked above contain the information you are looking for? If yes then we can close this question as a duplicate.